# Downloading Email Template as a PDF

Tags: email-template, pdf

I have an email template, querying the Email template and displaying it in VF page, with Fixed headers and footers in each page.

I need[image] to display fixed headers and footers in all the pages in PDF dynamically.

[image]

I need my header and footer as mentioned above, but its displaying inside Word Body.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a VisualForce page the best idea I can come up with to  repeat structures is using the `<apex:repeat>` tag.

This tag will allow you to repeat the structure within it, the number of times depends on the size of the array you set as the value.

You might need to define a array in your Controller to communicate VF how many times it must repeat.

I hope this helps!